# rearrange \volcite to delete p. and relocate volume number

Tags: citing, biblatex-chicago

I am using biblatex-chicago (notes) in my thesis, and I would like to use \volcite for citing multiple volumes from a book, because when I use \autocite to cite differnt volumes, each volume appears as a single entry in the bibliography.

Using the \autocite command the footnote appears as:

Abū-Bakr Muḥammad Ibn-ʿAbdallāh Ibn al-ʿArabī,Aḥkām Al-Qurʾān, 3rd ed., ed.Muḥammad ʿAbd al-Qādir ʿAṭṭā, vol. 1 (Beirut: Dār al-Kutub al-ʿIlmīya, 2003), 13
With volume number appears before place of publication, publisher and year.

Using \volcite command the footnote appears as:

Muḥammad ibn ʿUmar ar-Rāzī,Tafsīr Al-Faḫr Ar-Rāzī al-Muštahir Bi-t-Tafsīr al-Kabīr Wa-Mafātīḥ al-Ġayb, 1st ed., 32 vols. (Beirut: Dār al-Fikr, 1981), vol. 3, p. 2

Is there a way when using \volcite to delete the p. before page number and relocate volume number to replace total number of volumes, without affecting how the entries look in the bibliography?

MWE

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{scrextend}
%%%%language settings%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeAutoQuote{»}{«}
\usepackage[backend=biber,notes, isbn=false,doi=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}
@mvbook{ibnal-arabiAhkamAlQuran2003,
  title = {Aḥkām Al-{{Qurʾān}}},
  author = {Ibn al-ʿArabī, Abū-Bakr Muḥammad Ibn-ʿAbdallāh},
  editor = {al-Qādir ʿAṭṭā, Muḥammad ʿAbd},
  date = {2003},
  edition = {3},
  volume = {1},
  publisher = {{Dār al-Kutub al-ʿIlmīya}},
  location = {{Beirut}},
  volumes = {4}
}

@mvbook{raziTafsirAlFahrArRazi1981,
  title = {Tafsīr Al-{{Faḫr}} Ar-{{Rāzī}} al-Muštahir Bi-t-Tafsīr al-Kabīr Wa-Mafātīḥ al-Ġayb},
  author = {ar- Rāzī, Muḥammad ibn ʿUmar},
  date = {1981},
  edition = {1},
  publisher = {{Dār al-Fikr}},
  location = {{Beirut}},
  volumes = {32}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\blindtext \autocite[13]{ibnal-arabiAhkamAlQuran2003}
\par
\blindtext \footnote{\volcite{3}[2]{raziTafsirAlFahrArRazi1981}}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that there are no unintended consequences for this, since `biblatex-chicago` is complex and difficult to modify, but here's a pretty simple way that works with your MWE.

I propose to redefine `\blx@defvolcitepostnote` to put the volume and postnote into the actual `volume` and `postnote` fields rather than into `volcitevolume` and `volcitepages`. The `postnote` field must also be cleared if no optional argument is given to `\volcite`.

The only other thing needed is to clear the `\AtVolcite` hook which otherwise aliases the `postnote` field format to `volcitenote`.

### MWE

```
%! TeX Program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@mvbook{ibnal-arabiAhkamAlQuran2003,
  title = {Aḥkām Al-{{Qurʾān}}},
  author = {Ibn al-ʿArabī, Abū-Bakr Muḥammad Ibn-ʿAbdallāh},
  editor = {al-Qādir ʿAṭṭā, Muḥammad ʿAbd},
  date = {2003},
  edition = {3},
  volume = {1},
  publisher = {Dār al-Kutub al-ʿIlmīya},
  location = {Beirut},
  volumes = {4}
}
@mvbook{raziTafsirAlFahrArRazi1981,
  title = {Tafsīr Al-{{Faḫr}} Ar-{{Rāzī}} al-Muštahir Bi-t-Tafsīr al-Kabīr Wa-Mafātīḥ al-Ġayb},
  author = {ar- Rāzī, Muḥammad ibn ʿUmar},
  date = {1981},
  edition = {1},
  publisher = {Dār al-Fikr},
  location = {Beirut},
  volumes = {32}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\makeatletter
\long\def\blx@defvolcitepostnote#1#2{%
  \def\abx@field@volume{#1}%
  \ifblank{#2}
    {\clearfield{postnote}}
    {\def\abx@field@postnote{#2}}}
\makeatother
\AtVolcite*{}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill

Filler text \autocite[13]{ibnal-arabiAhkamAlQuran2003}.

Filler text \avolcite{3}[2]{raziTafsirAlFahrArRazi1981}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Many thanks, it worked just fine with no unintended consequences so far.